# Resource for highlight syntax debugging

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I’ve been developing a Vim syntax file for ISC Bind 9.15+

The stock named.vim that came with Vim is quite outdated (V9.4)

About 89 syntaxes out of 498 have been completed so far to catch up.

But the new named.vim is now 2000+ lines long.  It’s still very fast.

I’m looking for HOWTOs or debugging techniques on large syntax files.

I am currently doing a [dual Vim terminal sessions (as described in [Egbert](https://egbert.net/blog/articles/debugging-bind9-syntax-file-of-vim.html)) using [Dr. Chip](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/)’s [HiTraceLinks/HiLinks](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vbafiles/hilinks.vba.gz).

Where can i find such syntax debugging resources?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you're looking for? You mention large files, so are you looking for help in benchmarking the syntax? Or do you want an inspector that can tell you which syntax gets applied to specific blocks of text? What kind of help do you need for debugging, or what kind of problem are you currently finding too hard to solve that you'd like to have help with?

Comment: Benchmarking, not a problem ... yet.  Two things:  1) Some kind of programming guide for Vim syntax highlighting, and 2) some kind of guide on debugging other than Dr. Chip's approach (which I think it's about the best one out there so far).  A page about the Vim syntax highlight debugging https://egbert.net/blog/articles/debugging-bind9-syntax-file-of-vim.html

Comment: Have you read _Learn Vimscript the Hard Way?_ It has three chapters on syntax highlighting: [Basic Syntax Highlighting](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/45.html), Advanced Syntax Highlighting and Even More Advanced Syntax Highlighting. Don't know if there's a focus on debugging but it's worth a skim.

Comment: It’s still pretty terse. At the moment, I’ve successfully created the 837 syntax rule set for Bind9 named.conf file.  It works.  Sometime, trial and error is the way to do.  I’ve been posting blogs on this largest Vim syntax file periodically.